# clock_nanosleep, time measurement between interrupt and process waking up

Tags: c

I'm trying to measure time between the moment process is waken up after thread blocking with clock_nanosleep and actual time it was waken up. Later on save the answers to array and with measurements print it to file but the problem is with making thread sleep.

```
    for(i ; i < number_of_answers ; i++)
    {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &deadline);

        deadline.tv_nsec += 250000;

        if(deadline.tv_nsec >= 1000000000)
        {
            deadline.tv_nsec -= 1000000000;
            deadline.tv_sec++;
        }

        clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &deadline, 0);

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);

        exec_time = (now.tv_sec - deadline.tv_sec) * 1000000000 + (now.tv_nsec - deadline.tv_nsec);
        table[i] = exec_time;
    }

    for(j ; j < number_of_answers ; j++)
    {   
        /*fopen, not implemented*/
        printf("table number: %i, value of table:%f\n", j, table[j]);
    }
```

Can anyone suggest me what should I correct to make it work? The output is

```
table number: 0, value of table:-249600.000000
table number: 1, value of table:-249900.000000
table number: 2, value of table:-249800.000000
table number: 3, value of table:-249800.000000
table number: 4, value of table:-249800.000000
table number: 5, value of table:-249800.000000
table number: 6, value of table:-249800.000000
table number: 7, value of table:-249800.000000
table number: 8, value of table:-249800.000000
table number: 9, value of table:-249700.000000
```

Comment: Thou shalt check the return value.https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ten-commandments.html

Comment: @Jasen: Maybe, but I don't think that's the problem here, unlss the system is broken and `clock_nanosleep` doesn't work.

Comment: @Jakub: What OS and cpu arch?

Comment: @Jasen perror says it is invalid argument

Comment: @R.. GitHub STOP HELPING ICE, PC is Windows 10 x86_64, im using Code Blocks 20.3 with MinGw, but I just rerun oldest version on ARM with Debian and it seems its working, the numbers are about 75us, so it was probably Windows reason? I had recently some problems with Microsoft Services maybe that's it, anyway if there is solution to repair it I'd love to hear how. Thank you.

Comment: @Jakub: `clock_nanosleep` returns the error code; it doesn't necessarily set `errno` (which `perror` uses). In any case, mingw probably just doesn't support `clock_nanosleep` on `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.

Comment: Mingw? well there's the problem, you only get whatever features microsoft exposes to MSVCRT, last I checked windows only had millisecond timing - but that was more than 10 years ago, and MSVCRT was even older.